# How to display custom error message in JSON Forms for Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-jsonschema-forms, jsonforms

This is my TSX code:

```js
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from "react";

//jsonforms import
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  materialRenderers,
  materialCells,
} from "@jsonforms/material-renderers";
import { JsonForms } from "@jsonforms/react";
import schema from "./schema.json";
import uischema from "./uischema.json";
import { createAjv } from "@jsonforms/core";

const InputTextField: FC = (): ReactElement => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const renderers = [...materialRenderers];
  const ajv = createAjv();

  ajv.addFormat("email", "[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]{2,3}");

  return (
    <JsonForms
      ajv={ajv}
      schema={schema}
      uischema={uischema}
      data={data}
      renderers={renderers}
      cells={materialCells}
      onChange={({ data, errors }) => setData(data)}
    />
  );
};

export default InputTextField;
```

I've been trying to validate the email field with regex like this: `ajv.addFormat("email", "[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]{2,3}");`

By passing the format in the schema (see below) now the field is correctly validated. However, the error message is the following:

[image]

How can I customize that error message?

For all the code, I've been following [this tutorial](https://kukshalkanishka.medium.com/customising-json-forms-7fc75f627fff). However, the section for customizing error message does not work. Seems like "inline" parameter inside ajv.addKeyword is no longer available.

My JSON Forms version is: ^3.0.0
I'm using TypeScript and React

I have the following schema:

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "description": "Please enter your name"
    },
    "birthDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Please enter your email.",
      "format": "email"
    }
  },
  "required": ["email"]
}
```

And UI Schema:

```js
{
  "type": "VerticalLayout",
  "elements": [{
    "type": "HorizontalLayout",
    "elements": [{
        "type": "Control",
        "scope": "#/properties/name"
      },
      {
        "type": "Control",
        "scope": "#/properties/email"
      },
      {
        "type": "Control",
        "scope": "#/properties/birthDate"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```